# Array in a Redux State, React

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I'm stuck and I can't find out how to store a dictionary in Redux State.

```
const productinuse = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'productinuse':
      return [...state, action.payload];
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export default productinuse;
```

```
animModal(product) {
    console.log(product);
    () =>
      store.dispatch({
        type: 'productinuse',
        payload: product,
      }),
      store.dispatch({type: 'toggleproductmodal'});
  }
```

Example of the dictionary that I'm trying to store on it :

```
{"UNIT": "Kg", "images": ["https://example.com/image.jpg"], "module_id": "1", "product_id": "6", "product_img": "example.com/image2.js", "product_name": "Ananas", "product_prix": "8.5", "product_text": "1 Kg Ananas."}
```

I always get the default empty array as a value.

**EDIT**

```
const initialState = {
  productinuse: [],
};
const productinuse = (state = initialState, action) => {
  console.log(action.payload + 'DEBUGGINS');
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'productinuse':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        productinuse: [...state, action.payload],
      });

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export default productinuse;
```

**EDIT 2 **

```
<TouchableOpacity
                  key={product.product_id}
                  style={{width: '50%', position: 'relative'}}
                  onPress={() =>
                    this.setState(
                      {
                        product: product,
                      },
                      (product) =>
                        store.dispatch({
                          type: 'productinuse',
                          payload: product,
                        }),
                      () => store.dispatch({type: 'toggleproductmodal'})}>
```

Now When I perform the action I'm getting a TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a Symbol.iterator method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

state:

```
const initialState = {
  productinuse: []
}
```

reducer:

```
const productinuse = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'productinuse':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        productinuse: [...state.productinuse, action.payload],
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export default productinuse;
```

Comment: [Thu Sep 10 2020 08:20:22.961]  LOG      {"productinuse": []}

Comment: Can you share your action?

Comment: @SaadElQorchi Don't forget to check new state in `useEffect`

Comment: the action, is it the way that I call dispatch ? I call animModal(product) on an onPress method of a touchableOpacity, when i console.log inside the function, I get the value. but not in redux, I did it with an integer the same way, and its working.  i dont know how to useEffect

Comment: @SaadElQorchi How do you check state?

Comment: mapStateToProps to get the value inside a component and then I simply console.log(this.props.product) even if i get nothing inside the component. i get this result : {"productinuse": []}.     there is maybe something that i did wrong

Comment: please check out new edit. And sorry, I really would like to do codesandbox but i dont know how

Comment: I've a mistake and edited my answer that time :) but you didn't change. `productinuse: [...state.productinuse, action.payload]`

Comment: Thank you so much !